# Working with multi-column sortable Items in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Here's my dilemma - I have a two-column list of elements (styled `<div>`s) that I need to make sortable.  With elements that live in one or the other column, this is easy - I just set up two columns, place my elements where they need to be initially, mark them as "sortable," and let jQuery do its magic.

However, I have two elements in the list that need to span *both* columns.  This, unfortunately, breaks the usability of the model.  If I stick with my standard 2-column setup, I run into situations where the wide elements overlap or underlap with elements in the other column.

I also tried iterating through both columns to reposition elements so there would be no overlap, but then I realized another issue: my second column (on the right) has no knowledge of the elements positioned in the first column (on the left).

Here's a stripped down example of my markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="column-1" class="column" style="width:400px;">
        <div id="item-1" class="item" style="width:200px;">
        ...
        </div>
        <div id="item-2" class="item wide" style="width:400px;">
        ...
        </div>
        <div id="item-3" class="item" style="width:200px;">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="column-2" class="column">
        <div id="item-4" class="item" style="width:200px;">
        ...
        </div>
        <div id="item-5" class="item" style="width:200px;">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The way this *should* line up is something like this table:

```
-------------------
| item 1 | item 4 |
|      item 2     |
| item 3 | item 5 |
-------------------
```

And each item can be dragged and dropped anywhere else, with items 1, 3, 4, 5 moving interchangeably between the two columns, and with item 2 moving up and down as necessary.  Realistically, you should also be able to end up with something like this:

```
-------------------
| item 1 |        |
|      item 2     |
| item 3 | item 5 |
| item 4 |        |
-------------------
```

But with a standard column model (i.e. the stock jQuery examples, the only resources I can find from several days of Google searches, and every attempt I've made thus far) this won't work.

So what can I do to implement this kind of layout with the jQuery UI Sortable plug-in so I can continue building my UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I invested more time and have hacked my way through to one possible solution.  It still has its problems, but I'm at least getting *most* of the functionality I need.

The trick is to create multiple sortable elements and to nest them.  So my document structure becomes:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="macro-section-1" class="macro fixed" style="width:400px">
    <div class="column" style="width:400px;">
        <div id="item-1" class="item" style="width:200px;">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div id="item-4" class="item" style="width:200px;">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="item-2" class="item wide macro mobile" style="width:400px;">
....
</div>
<div id="macro-section-2" class="macro fixed" style="width:400px;">
    <div class="column" style="width:400px;">
        <div id="item-3" class="item" style="width:200px;">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div id="item-5" class="item" style="width:200px;">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then, you instantiate 2 different sortables - one to sort the smaller 1-column elements among themselves and the other to sort the 1-column "macro" elements.  Note that there are 3 macro elements on this page:

1. The first macro element is "fixed" and has two columns for smaller sortables
2. The second macro element is "mobile," meaning it will also be a sortable
3. The third macro element is "fixed" and has two columns for smaller sortables

The code to make this all work together is remarkably simple:

```
$('.column').sortable({
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    connectWith: '.column',
    handle: '.section-handle',
    cursor: 'move',
    opacity: 0.7
});

$('#wrapper').sortable({
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: '.section-handle',
    cursor: 'move',
    opacity: 0.7
});
```

This connects the various `.column` elements so that the 1-column elements can be interchanged anywhere on the page.  The second code block turns the entire `#wrapper` element into its own sortable, which allows you to reposition the large, 2-column element on the page as well.

Since I'm explicitly declaring the drag handle (a div with the `section-handle` class attached to each sortable element), you don't need a `cancel` property on your `sortable()` call ... the "fixed" macro elements don't have the drag handle to begin with, so they can't be manually repositioned.  However, you can drag the "mobile" macro element (`item-2`) to anywhere else on the page without any problem.

The only issue I'm still facing (and it's more a personal frustration than anything else) is that the two sortables (`#wrapper` and `.column`) aren't aware of one another.  So if you have the following layout:

```
-------------------
| item 1 |        |
|      item 2     |
| item 3 | item 5 |
| item 4 |        |
-------------------
```

And items 3, 4, and 5 are in the same sortable container, then you can't drag item 2 in between items 3 and 4.  When dragging item 2, the page is aware of 3 sortable elements - the block containing item 1, the block you're dragging (item 2), and the block containing items 3, 4, and 5.  So while from a usability perspective you *should* be able to place item 2 below items 3 and 5 ... the method I've outlined above doesn't allow you to do that.

So for now it works, but there's definitely massive room for improvement here.